# Horizontal JS page scrolling on button click

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I'm looking for pretty much the same navigation function that is used on http://mercertavern.com/ but without the scrollbar itself. I only want it to scroll when a menu item is clicked. Any simple code for this? Everything that is a clue in the right direction is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Which navigation function? I don't see a horizontal scroll bar. Please be more specific. And what have you tried so far?

Comment: The scrollbar is right above the footer. It scrolls the content div horizontally just like the menu does. I just want the function that scrolls my content when clicking in the menu though. I have tried a few different scripts but none of them seem to work the way I want them to work. I'm pretty new to javascript stuff too.